# Optimal paths between two closed lines

Tags: optimization

Imagine I have an outer shape and an inner shape (that may overlap like the following picture)

[image: My pic]

Is there any algorithm or mathematical property I can use to find a third set of points which will be in the middle of the two?

Comment: You could plot the locus of points whose distance from the two curves is equal. However, this may require some cleanup where the curves intersect: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mNjBD.png

Comment: Are your two sets of points indexed in the same way? That is, do you have Red1, Red2, Red3... and corresponding Green1, Green2, Green3? If so, then the simple averaging (Red1+Green1)/2, (Red2+Green2)/2... may be enough.